# How to use transition element animation into one activity?

Tags: android, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I have an `activity` with `recyclerView` in the bottom and an `imageView` on the top of the `recyclerView`.

I show some images in the `recyclerView` and when the user selects an item it will set on top `imageView`.

I want to set selected image from the `recyclerView` with a transition animation into the `imageView`.

I set `android:transitionName="img_selected"` in my activity's xml and adapter's xml.
And I defined a listener for the `recyclerView` like this:

```
    @Override
      public void onItemClick(ImageView img, int position) {

        loadSelectedImage(position);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

          Pair[] pair = new Pair[2];
          pair[1] = new Pair<View, String>(img, "img_selected");
          ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MotionActivity.this, pair);
          options.toBundle();
        }

  }
```

Also, I added this line to the application theme:

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

but it doesn't work.
How can I do that?

This is an image of my application:

[image]
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @SantanuSur I don't think so. I want to use transition element in one activity between  my recyclerView items and imageView that both are in the same activity.

Comment: hold on i am adding an answer... !!

Comment: @SantanuSur Thank you